# How to close socket after writing in libevent with bufferevents?

Tags: c++, c, io, libevent

Here is an example of echo TCP server from libevent book. 
How can I modify it to close a socket after each write. I know that I can close a socket connection by calling bufferevent_free(), but I don't understand how use it to close connection every time I send an echo to the socket.

```
#include <event2/listener.h>
#include <event2/bufferevent.h>
#include <event2/buffer.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void
echo_read_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx)
{
        /* This callback is invoked when there is data to read on bev. */
        struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
        struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(bev);

        /* Copy all the data from the input buffer to the output buffer. */
        evbuffer_add_buffer(output, input);
}

static void
echo_event_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *ctx)
{
        if (events & BEV_EVENT_ERROR)
                perror("Error from bufferevent");
        if (events & (BEV_EVENT_EOF | BEV_EVENT_ERROR)) {
                bufferevent_free(bev);
        }
}

static void
accept_conn_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener,
    evutil_socket_t fd, struct sockaddr *address, int socklen,
    void *ctx)
{
        /* We got a new connection! Set up a bufferevent for it. */
        struct event_base *base = evconnlistener_get_base(listener);
        struct bufferevent *bev = bufferevent_socket_new(
                base, fd, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);

        bufferevent_setcb(bev, echo_read_cb, NULL, echo_event_cb, NULL);

        bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);
}

static void
accept_error_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, void *ctx)
{
        struct event_base *base = evconnlistener_get_base(listener);
        int err = EVUTIL_SOCKET_ERROR();
        fprintf(stderr, "Got an error %d (%s) on the listener. "
                "Shutting down.\n", err, evutil_socket_error_to_string(err));

        event_base_loopexit(base, NULL);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct event_base *base;
        struct evconnlistener *listener;
        struct sockaddr_in sin;

        int port = 9876;

        if (argc > 1) {
                port = atoi(argv[1]);
        }
        if (port<=0 || port>65535) {
                puts("Invalid port");
                return 1;
        }

        base = event_base_new();
        if (!base) {
                puts("Couldn't open event base");
                return 1;
        }

        /* Clear the sockaddr before using it, in case there are extra
         * platform-specific fields that can mess us up. */
        memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
        /* This is an INET address */
        sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
        /* Listen on 0.0.0.0 */
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0);
        /* Listen on the given port. */
        sin.sin_port = htons(port);

        listener = evconnlistener_new_bind(base, accept_conn_cb, NULL,
            LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE|LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE, -1,
            (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
        if (!listener) {
                perror("Couldn't create listener");
                return 1;
        }
        evconnlistener_set_error_cb(listener, accept_error_cb);

        event_base_dispatch(base);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you try to use `bufferevent_free()` and what is that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of documentation - you should put `bufferevent_free(bev);` at the end of `echo_event_cb()` function, this should close the connection after echoing user data back w/o waiting the client to close it. This should work this way till you use `BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE`  when creating **bev** buffer event.